# RecyclerView обновить данные свайпом вверх

Tags: android

Есть RecyclerView. В нем отображается 10 записей, которые предварительно загружены из сети. С течением времени, некоторые записи могут быть удалены или добавлены новые. Мне нужно загрузить их и обновить данные в адаптере по событию свайпа вверх. Не могу понять как отследить это действие. Т.е. к примеру на экране 10 элементов списка, делаем свайп вверх и в адаптер загружаются измененные данные. Как отследить это действие?)

Comment: SwipeRewfreshLayout посмотрите может подойти

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.

Comment: отлично, тогда я сейчас немного опишу ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout), когда хотите обновить контент с помощью вертикального жеста. Жест обрабатывается в OnRefreshListener. SwipeRefreshLayout будет уведомлять слушателя каждый раз, когда жест снова будет завершен. Сам слушатель отвечает за правильное определение того, когда нужно инициировать обновление своего содержимого.

-Если слушатель определяет, что не должно быть обновления, он должен вызвать `setRefreshing (false)`, для отмены визуальной индикации обновления.

-Если view хочет показать только анимацию прогресса, она должна вызвать `setRefreshing (true)`

-Для отключения анимации жеста, используйте `setEnabled (false)`